# Adjust the "this is comment" default comment from low quality review based on their reputation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues

I've noticed that the default comment for comments posted as answers is

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

even for those who don't have enough reputation for commenting. Can we have it depend on this? I mean the "leave a comment" imperative is somewhat wrong/disappointing since they can't do so – I'd expect something like

> This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation, you can critique or request clarification from an author using comments below their post.

..and may be something like

> Until then, please ask and answer questions that you can answer without further clarification.

after it.

Answer (score 7):

Already works this way:

[image: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.]

If the author of the post being reviewed has earned [the Comment Everywhere privilege](/help/privileges/comment) *or* is answering their own question, the reviewer can leave this comment:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Otherwise, they get the comment shown above:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Ok, sorry, I wan't attentive enough. It seemed to me that when I went back, I saw a comment for a "high-rep" user left by me to a "low-rep" user by probably I've mistaken. At least I haven't found such a thing when rewinded some history.

Comment: I'll leave this thread non-deleted for some time, in case I faced some bug that repeats, though.

Comment: @YakovL This question has an upvoted answer, you cannot delete it.

Comment: @TinyGiant yeap, now only can vote to do so. But, nevermind